# Are CSS transitions for SVG elements on the horizon?

Tags: svg

I've made this example. It uses CSS transitions so that when the SVG rect elements have their widths changed, they animate smoothly to the new width. It only works in Chrome (and Opera FWIW). Are IE and FF likely to support this any time soon?

NB: I haven't tried Edge.

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
    rect {
        transition: width ease-in-out .5s;
    }
</style>

<svg width="900" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000">
    <rect id="myRect1" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect id="myRect2" x="0" y="100" width="0" height="100" fill="green"></rect>
    <rect id="myRect3" x="0" y="200" width="0" height="100" fill="yellow"></rect>
    <rect id="myRect4" x="0" y="300" width="0" height="100" fill="pink"></rect>
    <rect id="myRect5" x="0" y="400" width="0" height="100" fill="#ddd"></rect>
</svg>

<script>
    setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect1').setAttribute('width', '500px');}, 0);
    setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect2').setAttribute('width', '500px');}, 200);
    setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect3').setAttribute('width', '500px');}, 400);
    setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect4').setAttribute('width', '500px');}, 600);
    setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect5').setAttribute('width', '500px');}, 800);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Soon, no. Sometime yes.

Comment: under consideration in Edge https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/svg2/

Answer (score 0):

But you can get it working like this ...

```js
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect1').setAttribute('width', '500');}, 0);
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect2').setAttribute('width', '500');}, 200);
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect3').setAttribute('width', '500');}, 400);
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect4').setAttribute('width', '500');}, 600);
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('myRect5').setAttribute('width', '500');}, 800);
```

```css
svg { 
  display: block;
  transition: width ease-in-out .5s; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="myRect1" width="0" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="100" fill="red"/>
</svg>
<svg id="myRect2" width="0" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="100" fill="green"/>
</svg>
<svg id="myRect3" width="0" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="100" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>
<svg id="myRect4" width="0" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="100" fill="pink"/>
</svg>
<svg id="myRect5" width="0" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="100" fill="#ddd"/>
</svg>
```